# Is there a way to search what are last dynamic statement that have executed?

Tags: oracle

Is there table in oracle that note which dynamic sql statement have been recently done.
( like "dba_source" to search a package)

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference in the kernel between dynamic and non-dynamic SQL. You can look into v$sql and v$sql derivatives to see what is being executed (or recently executed, or look into dba_hist_sql... views for older statements, though there's no guarantee that you'll see all of them. Note this requires diag pack license.